# Programmatic access Linked Master / Child fields in Access

Tags: ms-access

How do I programmatically get the current linked value on a subForm in access. The documented  string property subForm.LinkMasterFields throws an error when I try to reference it.

Comment: Sorry I speed typed this. The documented property is subForm.LinkMasterFields. Is this the wrong approach however with msaccess ?

Answer (score 1):

LinkMasterFields will give you the name of the field it's linking on. Try this and see what it says

```
MsgBox Me.subForm.LinkMasterFields
```

If you want to get a value from a field on the subform you can get it like this

```
MsgBox Me.subForm.Form.field_1
```

or directly with

```
MsgBox subFormRealName.Form.field_1

''// n.b.: you're running with scissors if you do this - especially if you have 
''// the possibility of having the same subForm open multiple times at once
''// e.g., on the same form or on two different forms at once.
```

Comment: I would caution against ever using an unspecified reference to controls on a form or report. Thus, I'd say never to use your third suggestion.

Comment: I was looking to retrieve the current linked value on the subform to act on. 

I eventually worked around this using tabbed pages, using 2 subforms rather than 1 and trying to determine the linked value on it. I am yet to find out if the original technique works though. Thanks